# Format a textbox to include the '£'

Tags: razor

I have a text box which I would like to include a £ sign whenever the user begins to type in a number.

For example: £32

How would I do this:

```
@Html.TextBox("amountFrom", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "£" })
```

At the moment I just have a placeholder which puts a '£' sign in until the user types in an number. I would like the sign to appear immediately after the user starts typing.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix would be to use JavaScript or jQuery. When the text box changes, a £ is added to the front of whatever is already in the text box.

```
@Html.TextBox("amountFrom", "", new { @class = "form-control", @id="price" })

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#price').on('input',function() { 
        var price = $('#price').val();
        if (price.substring(0, 1) == '£')
        {
            price = price.substring(2);
        }

        $('#price').val('£ ' + price);
    });
});
</script>
```

See this fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/49gdh95z/

A slightly better solution might be to use CSS that shows a background image of a pound sign, like StackOverflow uses to show a magnifying glass image on it's search box.

A fiddle for this example can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/7pjm9v66/

Note that this second example adds the pound sign immediately after something is typed into the input box (and doesn't display beforehand). If you wanted to have the pound sign always display, then you can of course omit the JavaScript and move the CSS it applies directly to the `#price` element in the CSS.